# PHP : Multiple An Array Based On user count

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this :

```
$z =array (Self, Manager);
```

what I want is if `$count_member`  equal to 3 user

```
$count_member = count($member);
```

I want the array $z become multiple by 3 and assign to variable $X

```
$X = array(Self, Manager,Self, Manager,Self, Manager);
```

how can I archive that.. I try to used array_push and it not work. Thanks

Comment: You should do some PHP tutorials before asking questions like this.

Comment: The question doesn't make any sense. It seems as though you don't have a good understanding of how to use arrays... Among other things. I'm fairly confident that if you do some basic tutorials you will answer your own question.

Comment: that why i asked that question.. if it wrong please explain or modify anything..i come here to learn..:S what i want is the array become double based on counter..

Comment: What you're probably looking to do is a multidimensional array. And you're probably also looking to append a copy of $z to another array X amount of times. This is all extremely basic and is easily covered by numerous tutorials. Unfortunately (please take no offense), I can't fully understand what you want. You'll have to reword it with some context so that we can help you do it correctly. But again, if you do some tutorials it should become very obvious.

Comment: i have edited my question, do u understand now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try doing this

```
$z = array();
for($x = 0; $x < count($member); $x++){
    array_push($z, "self", "manager");
}
```